# Calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals

Tags: avl-tree, interval-tree

Calculate the maximum number of overlapping intervals with some conditions about operations:

1. Insert an interval: O(logN)
2. Remove an interval: O(logN)
3. Calculate(the maximum number of overlapping intervals): O(1)

I think this problem can be solved by using avl tree (suitable for Insert and Remove operations) but I dont know how to design avl tree to satisfy requirement of Calculate operation.

Edit: Example: [start, end)

Input: [1,2),[3,4),[1,6),[3,6),[6,7)

Output: 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Red Black tree and implement a Point of Maximum Overlap method.

The pseudo-code is in this link. [Point of Maximum Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780324/point-of-maximum-overlap)