# Calculating the maximum number of busy channels in a phone system

Tags: algorithm, telephony

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for calculating the maximum number of busy channels in the telephone system.
There is a Call Data Registration (CDR) file, which specifies the begin (TB) and end (TE) time of each call.
From it one can build an array T: ( (T1B, T1E), (T2B, T2E), (T3B, T3E), (T4B, T4E), (T5B, T5E), (T6B, T6E), (T7B, T7E), (T8B, T8E), (T9B, T9E) )
Multiple calls can occur simultaneously. Each call occupies one channel.
Example is in the attached picture. T - time, N - number of channels.
As you can see, there is a maximum of 4 occupied channels between T6B and T2E.
In principle, there can be several such maximum values.
I have some basic ideas how to start working on this, вut I am sure that this is a well-known problem that has a solution in the form of a proven algorithm.
[image: Calls and channels]

Comment: You need to look at the use of an [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(unit)) analysis

Answer (score 2):

You are right it is indeed a common problem. You can state it this way: Given an array of segments find a maximum number of intersecting segments.

*Intuition*

Basically, you can look at your image. Declare cumulative variable, then go form left to right, any time the call is started you add one, when the call is ended you substract one. All time maximum value of variable is the answer.

*Algorithm*

Let `segments` be an array of pairs `(start, end)` of length `N`.

Construct array `events` of pairs `(time, event)`, where

- `time` equals to all possible `start` and `end` from `segments`;
- `event` equals to `1` if `time` is a start of any segment and `-1` if it is an end.

Sort array `events` in ascending order.

Let `cur = 0` be a cumulative variable.
Let `mmax = 0` be a maximum number of intersecting segments.

Iterate over array `events` and on every iteration:

1. Add current value to `cur`
2. Set `mmax` to maximum between `mmax` and `cur`

`max` is an answer.

[Different solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-of-intersections-possible-for-any-of-the-n-given-segments/).

*Note*

You should properly handle situations when in any given moment one call is ending and another one is starting (which event comes first?).

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey. This is the straightforward solution that I was thinking about, too. Of course it should work. I asked a question here in hope to find some non-evident efficient algoritm. I came across a mention of using a red-black tree algorithm to solve this problem. But I haven't figured out how to use it yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780324/point-of-maximum-overlap

Comment: @Vodnik, I don't think it's possible to solve this problem with better complexity than `O(NlogN)`. If you find any interesting or fast solution, please leave link somewhere there.